# MySQL Connecting string using ODBC drivers

Tags: mysql, database, odbc

I am uploading a ASP.NET website which us MySQL as database and I am not able to open a connection to database on my server.
The website was working fine on localhost but on server it throws an exception:

The server is provided with MySQL ODBC 5.0 drivers as they say.
Connection string I am using is:

```
connectionString="driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=(local); Database=db_name; Connection Timeout=60; uid=username;pwd=1234;"
```

Is this the correct way of connecting to database?

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you tried `ConnectionTimeout` without the space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (if you havnt checked out the link):

```
connectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=myDataBase; User=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Option=3;"
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I used string provided by you and changed odbc driver version to 3.51 and it is working.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out several connection strings for MySQL with ODBC drivers at:

www.connectionstrings.com/mysql#p31

Comment: Copy and pasting directly from a site ( http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql#p31 ) isn't really that helpful in solving his problem. Or at least just post the link instead of spitting out the site ad verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

> The server is provided with MySQL ODBC 5.0 drivers as they say

You're using the 5.1 driver in your connection string - have you tried changing this to 5.0?